# Facebook takes only one account for sign in device while developing android app

Tags: android, facebook

I need some help regarding facebook sign in problem while developing android app. I am developing android app and intergrated facebook sdk successfully. I have installed facebook .apk in emulator for testing purpose. When I run my app on emulator and sign in with facebook app it works successfully. When I run it on real device it works successfully but for only one facebook account that is my own. It does not take other users to sign in with facebook. Please share your experience and solution for this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your app is in developing mode....you need to make it public to do so. Following are steps,
1. Go to your app "`Settings`" and provide "Contact Email".
2. Now go to "`Dashboard`".
3. Under your app name you will see "This app is public and available to all users[?]"
4. Now click on "`[?]`"
5. You will be redirected to next page where you will see "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" under app name.
6. Enable the button to "`YES`". That's it

Now you can use every device to sign in your app.
....cheers :)